# Only display some html if a row is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [DataTables](http://datatables.net) and have this code to highlight the rows selected:

```
    /* Click event handler */
    $('#items-table tbody tr').live('click', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = jQuery.inArray(id, aSelected);

        if ( index === -1 ) {
            aSelected.push( id );
        } else {
            aSelected.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );
```

What I would like to do is only display the following html if one or more rows are selected:

```
<p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="delete">Delete selected rows</a>           
</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('#items-table tbody tr.row_selected').length > 0){
    $('#delete').show();
}
else {
    $('#delete').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by doing this after the toggleClass

```
if($('#items-table tbody tr.row_selected').length > 0) {
    $("p").show();
else
    $("p").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that checks on every click how many rows are selected.

For example:

```
function checkRows(){
    if( $('.row_selected').length > 0 ){
       $('#delete').show();
    }else{
       $('#delete').hide();
    }
}
```

Then have this on the delete button:

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    $('.row_selected').slideUp(200,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $(this).hide(); // Hide delete button again
});
```

Hope that helps :)